# How to compare two OpenAPI JSON files using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, openapi

I download an OpenAPI file from localhost and convert it to .json. It becomes something like this:

```json
"components":{"responses":{"r200":{"content":{"application/json":{"schema":{"properties" ....
```

I'm doing this using this JavaScript code:

```js
const processData = async () => {
  const req = await axios.get('http://localhost:5004/swagger');
  let reqJson = JSON.stringify(req.data);
  fs.writeFile('swagger.json', reqJson, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  })
}
processData()
```

If there are any changes in the OpenAPI file on localhost, I want to download it, convert to .json, save it as a new file and compare with the original `swagger.json`. It will be the same to previous code, but

```
fs.writeFile('newSwagger.txt' ....
```

And changes has to be in error field in url.

Question: How can I compare these files, and show any changes in a popup on a web site like:

> Attention: there is changes in Backend API:
> Missing api/xxx/yyy
> Added api/zzz/yyy

Comment: Aside: if it's JSON you should probably save it with a `.json` extension.

Comment: I think you will accomplish it easier parsing de JSON an compare it rather than using a .txt

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: add question for you @Hogan

Comment: Consider using specialized OpenAPI diff tools such as [openapi-diff](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-diff), [oasdiff](https://github.com/Tufin/oasdiff), [bump diff](https://github.com/bump-sh/cli#usage), [option diff](https://www.useoptic.com/docs/openapi-diff) or similar.